# Why is my Blazor Javascript initializer not loaded?

Tags: javascript, blazor, maui

Following [the MSDN documentation about Javascript Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-6.0#javascript-initializers), I am trying to add one to my MAUI+Blazor project.

I added a file called `MauiBlazorTemplate.lib.module.js` (my project's name is "MauiBlazorTemplate") at the root of the web resources folder (`wwwroot`).

I added in this latter the following code to test if Blazor loads it:

```js
export function afterStarted(blazor) {
    alert("afterStarted");
    console.log("afterStarted");
}
```

But got no alert nor log.

I saw in [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37078) people writing `.module.lib.js` instead of `.lib.module.js`, so I tried both but still got no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new project and reproduced your problem.

After searching, I found it was an known issue on the github:[Blazor hybrid JS initializers dont work](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15201), you can follow up it.